# Excel- cumulative sum of clusters in dynamic range

Tags: excel-formula, dynamic, sum, range, offset

I have the dynamic range A (A#) and I want to calculate the cumulative sum of each "subrange" in B. The result musst be something as shown in column B. In other words I need a dynamic function/ formula which recognises the consecutive numbers in A und computes their total each time.

[image: A is a Dynamic range (A#) containing the input number and B should have the sum of each range containing consecutive numbers (1 or 0)]

Comment: Not a single question that you have raised on SO has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only managed to solve this with a helper column C

```
C1: 1
C2: =IF(A1=A2,C1,C1+1)
```

C2 is draggable all the way down where you need it

```
B1: =IF(A1=A2,"",SUMIFS(A1,A1,A1))
B2: =IF(A2=A3,"",SUMIFS($A$1:A2,$C$1:C2,C2,$A$1:A2,A2))
```

B2 is draggable all the way down where you need it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 you can use this LET to create a dynamic array that spills into Column B as you have shown:

```
=LET( a, A1#,
        sa, SCAN( 0, a, LAMBDA(a,b, a + b ) ),
        rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( a ) ),
        a_1, INDEX( a, rSeq + 1 ),
        change, IFERROR( a_1 <> a, 1 ),
        sChange, SCAN( 0, change*sa, LAMBDA(a,b, MAX( a, b ) ) ),
        IF( change, sChange - IF( rSeq=1, 0, INDEX( sChange, rSeq - 1) ), "" ) )
```

where **A1#** is the input array.

[image]